# MySQL Employee Database java.sql.SQLException: url cannot be null

Tags: java, mysql

I am creating an employee database in java but keep getting a "url can not be null" error. Here is my code for my main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean quit = false;
        String input = "";
    //  SimpleDataSource.init(args[0]);
    //  Database.createDB();

        while (quit == false) {
            System.out.println("Choose an Option: A)dd, S)earch, Q)uit");
            input = in.next();
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                System.out.println("Choose an Option: E)mployee");
                input=in.next();
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter new Employee ID: ");
                        int EmpID = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
                    String fName = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Last Name: ");
                        String lName = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Skill: ");
                        String skill1 = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Department ID: ");
                        String deptID = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Skill ID: ");
                        String skillID = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Employee Email: ");
                        String empEmail = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Employee Phone Number: ");
                        String empPhone = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Department Title: ");
                        String depTitle = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Supervisor's ID: ");
                        String supID = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Supervisor's Last Name: ");
                        String supLName = in.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter Supervisor's First Name: ");
                        String supFName = in.next();
                    Database.addEmployee(EmpID,fName, lName, skill1, deptID, skillID, empEmail, empPhone, depTitle, supID, supLName, supFName);

            } 
            }else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                System.out.println("Choose an Option: E)mployee, S)kill, E)mail");
                input=in.next();
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Employee ID: ");
                    int id = in.nextInt();
                    Database.findEmployee(id);
                } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Skill: ");
                    String empSkill1= null;
                    Database.findSkill(empSkill1);
                }
            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
                System.out.println("Enter Employee Email: ");
                String empEmail=in.next();
                Database.findEmail(empEmail);


            } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        in.close();

}

}
```

Here is the class that creates the database:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Database {

static int EmployeeID = 000000001;

/**
 * Creates Database
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static void createDB() throws SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection()) {
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        stat.execute("CREATE TABLE Employees (EmployeeID VARCHAR(9), EmployeeFName VARCHAR(15), EmployeeLName VARCHAR(15), Skill1 VARCHAR(30), DepartmentID CHAR(2), SkillID CHAR(4), Email VARCHAR(40), Phone CHAR(10)");
        stat.execute("INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (000000001, 'Bob', 'Ross', ???, ???, ???)");
        stat.execute("INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (000000002, 'Chuck', 'Brown', ???, ???, ???)");
        stat.execute("INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (000000003, 'Charles', 'Fischer', ???, ???, ???)");
        conn.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Adds a customer to database using given information
 * @param cFname First Name
 * @param cLname Last name
 * @param Skill1 Skill 1
 * @param Skill2 Skill 2
 * @param Skill3 Skill 3
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static void addEmployee(int EmpID, String EmpFname, String EmpLname, String sk1, String deptID, String skillID, String email, String phoneNum, String depTitle, String supID, String supLName, String supFName) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection()) {
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        stat.execute("INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (" + EmployeeID + ", '" + EmpFname + "', '" + EmpLname + "', '"
                + sk1 + ","+deptID+","+skillID+","+email+","+phoneNum+","+depTitle+","+supID+","+supLName+","+supFName+",");
        conn.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Increases loyalty value of given customer
 * @param CustID Customer ID
 * @throws SQLException
 */


/**
 * Adds Employee to database using given info
 * @param itemName Item Name
 * @param price Item Price
 * @throws SQLException
 */


/**
 * Finds Employee information using given ID
 * @param EmployeeID Employee ID
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static void findEmployee(int EmpID) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection()) {
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID = " + EmployeeID;
        ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery(query);

        while (result.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                System.out.print(result.getString(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        conn.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Finds Skill information using given Skill
 * @param Skill1 Skill 1
 * @param Skill2 Skill 2
 * @param Skill3 Skill 3
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static void findSkill(String sk1) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection()) {
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Skill1 ='"+sk1+"";
        ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery(query);

        while (result.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                System.out.print(result.getString(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        conn.close();
    }
}
public static void findEmail(String email) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection()) {
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Email = " + email;
        ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery(query);

        while (result.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                System.out.print(result.getString(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        conn.close();
    }
}
}
```

Here is my connection class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;


public class SimpleDataSource {

    private static String url;
    private static String username;
    private static String password;

public static void init(String fileName) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException

{
    Properties props= new Properties();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    //fileName= "database.properties.properties";
    props.load(in);

    String driver = props.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
    url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
    username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
    if(username == "admin") {username = "";}
    password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
    if (password == "secret" ) {password = "";}
    if (driver != null) {Class.forName(driver);}

}


public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
{
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}

}
```

Here is my jdbc database.properties file:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:derby:BigJavaDB;create=true
With other databases, you may need to add entries such as these
jdbc.username=admin
jdbc.password=secret
jdbc.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at SimpleDataSource.getConnection(SimpleDataSource.java:36)
    at Database.findEmployee(Database.java:89)
    at Main.main(Main.java:77)
```

I have tried basically everything at this point and need some help.  I have tried debugging it multiple times but can't seem to find the error. Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked that after `props.load(in);` your `props` object actually has properties?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDataSource.init(...) is never called so url won't be set.

Some remarks about the code you have posted. Why is every method static and why don't you use any principles of object oriented programming? I don't know what your developer experience with Java is (without being offending). So there might be a very good reason for using this application model. If you are relatively new, you should check those principles. It allows you to write more maintainable and less error prone code.

Comment: Thank you and yes I am relatively new to Java.

Comment: Everybody was new to Java at least once. Enjoy the language and its possibilities.